# How to store 2D Array in model of Django

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Problem:**
I am in need to store 2D array in one of the field of the Table.

**Example**

id:1

Teacher_name:"Amit"

time: [[9:00am, 2:00pm], [2:00pm,6:00pm], [6:00am, 9:00pm]] **# Need to store 2-D array kind of multiple time stamps in a field**,

code is here:

Model.py

```
class ScheduleClassification(models.Model):
    vendor_id = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="forever")
    day_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    time = #how do i make this field
```

how can i store this please let me know the best way to do this. in django models

Comment: What data do you want to store in your models `time` field? Available times in a week? You can probably do that without using 2d arrays, but I need more information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First it isn't a good way to store the whole array what you must do is
Create New Model That will have the start and end time of Lesson for Teacher and the Schedule

```py
class Lesson(models.Model):
   start = models.DateTimeField()
   end = models.DateTimeField()
   duration = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="forever")
   teacher = models.ForeignField(Teacher)
   schedule = models.ForeignField(Schedule)
```

this is a better way and you can create a function that will make the array you want

```py
# in the Schedule Class 
def create_array(self):
   array = []
   qs = Lesson.objects.filter(schedule=self)
   for lesson in qs.iterator():
     lesson = [ lesson.start , lesson.end]
     array.append(lesson)  
   return array
```

also you can make this function `property` to enhance it

Comment: Thanks for the Responses actually i am creating a model name Schedule classification i am adding a ss for which i need to create model to store the details from that template component. Link is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cQrlLTqhZZQapm_DLXrs7TEXu8GbzxEE/view?usp=sharing please gone through with this link and suggest me the way to create model for this.